# Pylons/Routes Did url_for() change within templates?

Tags: python, routes, pylons, mako

I'm getting an error:

```
GenerationException: url_for could not generate URL. Called with args: () {}
```

from this line of a mako template:

```
<p>Your url is ${h.url_for()}</p>
```

Over in my helpers.py, I do have:

```
from routes import url_for
```

Looking at the Routes-1.12.1-py2.6.egg/routes/util.py, I seem to go
wrong about line it calls _screenargs().

This is simple functionality from the Pylons book.  What silly thing am I doing wrong?  Was there a new url_current()?  Where?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't know `url_for()` (no arguments) was ever legal, but if it was and this is what you're referring to as "url_current", I believe the [new approach](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=11174779#What%27snewinPylons0.9.7%3F-%7B%7Burl%7D%7Dobject) is to use the `url` object, calling a method on it as `url.current()`.